# Как вывести записи содержащие только кириллицу?

Tags: oracle, сопоставление-с-образцом

имеются 3 поля ФАМИЛИЯ, ИМЯ, ООТЧЕСТВО, в них могут записать данные с использованием латинских букв, например в поле ИМЯ могут записать Саша где С-си. Мне нужно вывести записи содержащие только кириллические символы. Пробовал так но что-то ничего не выходит.

```
Select Fam, Im, Otc, from Table1 
where Fam not like '%[A-z]%' or Fam not like '%[a-z]%'
or Im not like '%[A-Z]%'
or Im not like '%[a-z]%'
or Otc not like '%[A-Z]%'
or Otc not like '%[a-z]%'
```

Comment: В смысле "ничего не выходит" - ничего не выбирается? Или наоборот выбирается всё?

Comment: У вас неправильно выполнено отрицание предиката. При отрицании `or` должен заменяться на `and`

Comment: *записи содержащие только кириллические символы* == "записи, НЕ содержащие ни одного НЕ кириллического символа". ```WHERE column NOT REGEXP '[^А-Я]'``` с применением case-insensitive collation.

Comment: @CrazyElf ничего не выбирается

Comment: @Akina ругается на неверный реляционный оператор REGEXP

Comment: А это потому, что кому-то лень указать точно используемую СУБД, включая точную её версию.

Comment: @Akina oracle 11.2.0

Comment: Для OracleDB нужно использовать [REGEXP_LIKE Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501). И гораздо проще всё конкатенировать и один раз проверить на шаблон, чем трахаться с каждым полем по отдельности.